# MySQL super query

Tags: mysql, heidisql

I am trying to get information from table_a and auto apply to table_b while increasing pointsA by 5 pointsB by 8 and pointsC by 10

Basically looking for a single script that takes the IDs from table_a ONLY in category 1 while selecting UNIQUE numbers in PlayerAmmount (like for example if 2 (or more) ID's in Category 1 have a PlayerAmmount of 555 it only lists the first one (aka ID 5 in this example) then ignores the rest after it sorts that it gets the ID from those similar then gets other IDs from that same category but with different PlayerAmmounts.

After it does all that and have a list of a few IDs (for example 5, 77, 553, 23523, 53223) it then takes those ID's and places them in table_b with unique entry's incrimented by 1 (like normal counting) and puts those id's into its own entry (like 1 is ID 5 from table_a) and then it takes the base numbers 5 8 10 and adds itself.

So for example row 1:

> entry = 1 ID = 5 pointsA = 5, pointsB = 8, and pointsC = 10

then row 2 MUST be adding itself like here:

> entry = 2 ID = 77, pointsA = 10, pointsB = 16, pointsC = 20

then row 3 is this:

> entry = 3, ID = 553, pointsA = 15, pointsB = 24, pointsC = 30

and so forth as all the IDs from table_a are input into table_b

So far my only attempts to anything in this is the following of different styles but this is all I can come up with. Anyone got a better working way that could work?

```
INSERT INTO table_b 
    (entry, ID, pointsA, pointsB, pointsC)
VALUES 
    ((SELECT max(entry) FROM table_b C) + 1, 
    (SELECT max(ID) FROM table_a in(SELECT DISTINCT PlayerAmmount FROM table_a WHERE Category=1)), 
    (SELECT max(pointsA) FROM table_b C) + 5, 
    (SELECT max(pointsB) FROM table_b C) + 8, 
    (SELECT max(pointsC) FROM table_b C) + 10;
```

Images:

Table_A

[image: tableA]

Table_B

[image: tableB]

Setup

[image: setup]

Comment: First, try and construct a simple SELECT statement that produces what you want to insert. Then use the INSERT FROM SELECT statement type.

Comment: Also, add your table schemas to your question.

Comment: pressing enter button 4 times made me post it for some reason was adding in the tables  the schema is just the basic stuff from xampp for testing database in its own thing

Comment: To go with the simple selection it would be

    SELECT `ID` FROM `table_a` WHERE `PlayerAmmount` IN (SELECT 
    DISTINCT `PlayerAmmount` WHERE `Category`=1) AND `Category`=1;

Comment: Don't put code in a comment, edit your question and put it there.

Comment: Also, add your table schemas to your question.